# Any function with the same polymorphic type as fmap must be equal to fmap?

Tags: haskell, functor

I'm reading the second edition of Programming in Haskell and I've came across this sentence:

> ... there is only one way to make any given parameterised type into a functor, and hence any function with the same polymorphic type as `fmap` must be equal to `fmap`.

This doesn't seem right to me, though. I can see that there is only one *valid* definition of `fmap` for each `Functor` type, but surely I could define any number of functions with the type `(a -> b) -> f a -> f b` which aren't equivalent to each other?

Why is this the case? Or, is it just a mistake by the author?

Comment: I tried to [find this text](https://books.google.com/books?id=olp7lAtpRX0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=programming+in+haskell&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_59SPqtLhAhXimOAKHRnIBOYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=only%20one%20way&f=false) in the book so I could check that the context doesn't change the meaning, but it doesn't seem to appear (in the edition Google Books has, at least). What page/chapter/section is that from? Are you sure you're quoting it precisely? Tiny variants in wording can matter a lot with these things.

Comment: I wonder if the author meant any function obeying the function laws must be fmap?

Comment: @DanielWagner page 163, third paragraph from the bottom. It looks like the book you linked is the first edition, whereas I'm reading the second edition.

Comment: @augustss I believe that must be what he meant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've misread what the author was saying.

> ...any function with **the same polymorphic type as `fmap`**...

This means, any function with the signature

```
Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

must be equivalant to `fmap`. (Unless you permit bottom values, of course.)

That statement is true; it can be seen quite easily if you try to define such a function: because you know nothing about `f` except that it's a functor, the only way to obtain a non-⊥ `f b` value is by fmapping over the `f a` one.

What's a bit less clear cut is the logical implication in the quote:

> there is only one way to make any given parameterised type into a functor, and **hence** any function with the same polymorphic type as fmap must be equal to fmap.

I think what the author means there is, because a `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` function must necessarily invoke `fmap`, and because `fmap` is always *the only* valid functor-mapping for a parameterised type, any `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` will indeed also in practice obey the functor laws, i.e. it will be *the* `fmap`.

I agree that the “hence” is a bit badly phrased, but in principle the quote is correct.

Comment: Aha! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: "in principle the quote is correct" Is it, if you take into account existence of types which can't be made into functors? I think it isn't, and "only one way" needs to be changed "at most one way".

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I don't think he's saying that any parameterised type can be a functor, I think he's saying that you can only have a single Functor implementation for any parameterised type (as opposed to potentially multiple). It's clearly meant to be a plain english description rather than rigorous language.

Comment: this answer literally makes no sense to me. If I have to write a function with a signature `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, the *only* thing I know about `f` is that it is a `Functor`. And the only thing I can use then, is `fmap`. Not "equivalent" -- there simple is nothing else at my disposal to use! (discounting bottoms of course). I can't assume that it is an Applicative or Monad, even. *Nothing.* And if I know something about a *specific* `f` and am using that specific thing to write this function, I can't use the constraint in the type -- *by definition*.

Comment: @WillNess ok. Well as it stands, your comment doesn't make a whole lot of sense _to me_; elaborate what you mean? It seems you're just confirming what I wrote in the middle paragraph.

Comment: I don't know. "will indeed also in practice obey the functor laws" seems to imply there are some options here for us to write *something*. there simply aren't, `fmap` is all we have. unless you consider something like ``foo g f = sum [1..10] `seq` fmap g f`` as a possibility, which I wasn't... so maybe it's just semantics. OTOH a question "is a function with fmap's signature *for some specific `f`, so, without the constraint* (optionally -- abiding by functor laws) always equivalent to `fmap`?" seems much more meaningful. that's what I meant.

Comment: @WillNess What about something like `flip (flip fmap)` as an option?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov that is in every meaningful sense the same as `fmap`. Certainly, it is _extensionally equal_ to `fmap`, and will practice probably even compile to the same machine code. Different source code does _not_ mean two functions are different.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yes, and I understood that to be the point of the answer.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov and hence my comment. :) fmap is fmap is fmap. for me, this says nothing. If fmap is the only tool at your disposal, a tool you're going to end up using is, non-surprisingly, fmap.

Comment: @WillNess But you can use `fmap` to produce functions that _aren't_ `fmap`, e.g. `void`, `(<$)`, `flip fmap`. It's just that none of them end up having type `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, and that anything you write using `fmap` with that type does end up being the same as `fmap`. As a counter-example, there _is_ more than one way to implement `Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a`: `const` and `(<*)`.

Comment: ...and perhaps more remarkably, `Applicative f => (a->b->c)->f a->f b->f c` has both `liftA2` and `flip . liftA2 . flip`, which are _not_ equivalent.

Comment: Or maybe even a closer analogy is that you can write infinitely many functions with the same type as `(<*>)` which aren't equivalent to it, e.g. `\f x -> (f <* x <* ... <* x) <*> x`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov of course you can go sideways but the question was how to 'get to the target'. And Applicative has lots of "tools to use", not just one (and *two* effectful values). the only substantive thing in play here is `fmap id === id`, which I now see, thanks to your comments.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the quote refers to this scenario. Assume we define a parameterized type:

```
data F a = .... -- whatever
```

for which we can write not only one, but two `fmap` implementations

```
fmap1 :: (a -> b) -> F a -> F b
fmap2 :: (a -> b) -> F a -> F b
```

satisfying the functor laws

```
fmap1 id = id
fmap1 (f . g) = fmap1 f . fmap1 g
fmap2 id = id
fmap2 (f . g) = fmap2 f . fmap2 g
```

Under these assumptions, we have that `fmap1 = fmap2`.

This is a theoretical consequence of the "free theorem" associated to `fmap`'s polymorphic type (see the comment under [Lemma 1](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap)).
Pragmatically, this ensures that the instance we obtain from `deriving Functor` is the only possible one.

Comment: In fact all that is necessary to verify is `fmap id = id` , the other comes for free

Answer (score 2):

It is a mistake. Here's some examples of functions with the same type as `fmap` for lists that are not `fmap`:

```
\f -> const []
\f -> concatMap (replicate 2 . f)
\f -> map (f . head) . chunksOf 2
\f -> map f . reverse
```

There are many more. In general, given a function `ixf` from list lengths to lists of numbers no bigger than that length (that is, valid indices into the list), we can build

```
maybeIt'sFmapLol :: (Int -> [Int]) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
maybeIt'sFmapLol ixf elemf xs = [map elemf xs !! ix | ix <- ixf (length xs)]
```

Use suitably lazy variants of `Int` to handle infinite lists. A similar function schema can be cooked up for other container-like functors.

Comment: Just as I expected. Thanks :)

Comment: But that's _not_ what the quote is claiming! For instance `const []` has type `q -> [a] -> [b]`, not `Functor f => (a->b) -> f a -> f b`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I think the "any given parameterised type" bit indicates that they are talking about `(a -> b) -> F a -> F b` for concrete choices of `F` (...say, `F = []`), not `Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`. But perhaps more context is needed to say for sure.

Comment: you could maybe simplify the `maybeIt'sFmapLol` example by taking progressively longer chunks and *diagonalizing* that matrix! or something :)

Comment: @WillNess I don't think so. Let's shorten `maybeIt'sFmapLol ixf elemf` to `g` for a moment; there's no guarantee that `g (xs ++ ys) = g xs ++ g ys` -- that is, that giving it longer lists produces things that start with the same suffix as the short list -- which you would need for taking progressively longer chunks to be correct.

Comment: @WillNess For a concrete example, consider `notFmap f [] = []; notFmap f xs = [f (last xs)]`, for which the true answer of `notFmap f xs` is not the diagonalization of `notFmap f` applied to any collection of prefixes of `xs`. It is an example of the general case given in the answer via `notFmap = maybeIt'sFmapLol $ \case 0 -> []; n -> [n-1]`.

Comment: ah, you mean it would not be general enough! it's fair. yes, my scheme would preserve every element, just mix their order. `[f (last xs)]` is a nice and simple example, maybe you ought to include it in the answer too. :)

Comment: looks like it is a bad wording, in the book. just before that quote the author refers to a passage where he explicitly mentions following the laws and the uniqueness of fmap. so he probably meant that as the context, and the wording in the quoted sentence was just sloppy in that it assumed that context, without saying so explicitly.